# Complete New to Ionic and Angular, need advice with external json request

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I just started with ionic and I know this is probably super easy. I've been reading about how to use ionic and angular, but haven't been able to figure this easy little task out.

I just want to simply pull json from an external file.  I'm still reading the docs, but can't manage to figure out how to do this just yet.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKwxpX

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic']);

    myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function() {

    //instead of hard coded json, I need to get json from an external source here

    this.items = [
        {title: "Item 1"},
        {title: "Item 2"},
        {title: "Item 3"},
        {title: "Item 4"},
        {title: "Item 5"},
     ]

  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        this.items.push(i);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `$http` call to make an ajax for external ajax and inside success call bind that result to the `$scope` variable.

Also you need to wrap title in `"` double quotes to make it valid json like `"title"`

**Markup**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">1000 Items</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item collection-repeat="item in main.items">
        {{item.title}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</body>
```

**Controller**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic']);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($http) {
  var main = this
  $http.get('data.json').success(function(data){
      main.items = data;
  })
});
```

**data.JSON**

```
[{
  "title": "Item 1"
}, {
  "title": "Item 2"
}, {
  "title": "Item 3"
}, {
  "title": "Item 4"
}, {
  "title": "Item 5"
}]
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ysC0VYkkq0ddjfo0rMoB?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you. I'm starting to understand how all of this works. I tend to have this habit of jumping into things without taking the time to read the basics.

Now I'm trying to do a fuzzy search with angular! Once I learn more I'm making the switch from jquery to angular

Comment: Keep it up ..Thanks:)